# Raster Styling from QGIS to Geoserver?

Tags: qgis, raster, geoserver, style

So I've got a number of different rasters with different values that represent similar data. I'm trying to create a default styling for them in geoserver. I've imported the QGIS style into geoserver. However the issue arises where the value ramp is based on the original raster's values.

How do I change the SLD so that it may be used for multiple rasters and not just the original?

Relevant SLD Code:

```
                    <sld:ColorMap>
                        <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#000000" label="Min" opacity="1.0" quantity="0"/>
                        <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#ff0000" label="Half" opacity="1.0" quantity="126"/>
                        <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#ffffff" label="Max" opacity="1.0" quantity="255"/>
                    </sld:ColorMap>
```

Comment: Is that really SLD code you have there?

Comment: Editted to reflect actual SLD code. Was QGIS default code to begin with.